# Redirect output of function to script output

Tags: bash

I made a script to encapsulate the use of rsync. Problem is, the output of stdout is lost, which prevent me from testing it. I know how to redirect to a file, but how can I redirect to the standart output?

myscript.sh

```
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "Not enought arg"
    exit 1
else
    rsync -avze ssh --partial --delete root@$1:/home/* /backup/$1
    exit 0
fi
```

I presume I just have to add `>` after rsync, but to what?

Comment: If `rsync` is producing any output and your script is as you've shown and if you're not redirecting the output of your script, then you should see the output.

Comment: You were both right, I just didn t noticed that rsync was hanging, but was actually outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neeed anything, output is automatically sent to stdout.

- Perhaps you should add `-v` (verbose) to rsync.
- Your `if` syntax is incorrect, you should see an error message. Post actual code.

Comment: Corrected the code, I am using putty and didn t found a easy way to copy paste, I ve been to quick when asking. You were both right, I just didn t noticed that rsync was hanging, but was actually outputting. I ll accept in 5min.